# How to check moov atom of a mp4 video is already faststart through ffmpeg api?

Tags: ffmpeg

We know that we can use ffmpeg command line `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -movflags faststart -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4` to move the moov atom to the start of a mp4 video, but how do we check the moov atom has already been mooven with command line, can we do this check by ffmpeg API? After many times test, I find the ffprobe command `ffprobe -i output.mp4 -v trace  2>&1 | grep -E "type:'mdat'|type:'moov'"` , after movflags faststart, the moov of output.mp4 is at front of mdat, but I still don't know whether it is right or not, and how to implementation it with ffmpeg API.

Before:

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb048904640] type:'mdat' parent:'root'
> sz: 263261034 48 263435919 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb048904640]
> type:'moov' parent:'root' sz: 174845 263261082 263435919

After:

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc170804380] type:'moov' parent:'root'
> sz: 174115 40 263435189 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc170804380]
> type:'mdat' parent:'root' sz: 263261034 174163 263435189